# Maven get relative path of dependency

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to get the relative path of the Maven dependency inside a `pom.xml`. Here is my project structure:

```
|-Project
  |--firstproject
     |---src
     |...
     |pom.xml
  |--secondproject
     |---src
     |...
     |pom.xml
```

Here is the `pom.xml` of `firstproject` where I'm importing `secondproject` as dependency.

```xml
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>secondproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

I would like to have the system path of Maven dependency like this:

```xml
<properties>
    <my.lib.path>${maven.dependency.com.foo.secondproject}</my.lib.path>
</properties>
```

Is that possible? Is there maybe another way to do this?

I know I can use `maven-antrun-plugin`, but I don't want the final `jar`. I want the relative path of the dependency like: `/home/user/projects/Project/secondproject`. Is there any way?

Comment: My first question: Why do you need that? What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise i need that to pass the path as parameter to another maven execution

Comment: Now it becomes more magic? What kind of Maven execution and why?

Comment: @khmarbaise something like:  `<execution>...<configuration><arguments>run --path=${my.lib.path}</arguments></configuration></execution>`

Comment: Where do you need that? Execution? For what ? Please make a full example of your project... and what is `run...`? For what purpose?

Comment: @MaxM As I said: Best thing would be a new question describing the complete use case.

Comment: @khmarbaise and JFabianMeier that are the requirements in my project. Thank you both for your taking time. My question was how can i get that and the answer was i can't do this. I will search for other tools and i will try also maven dependency plugin that JFabianMeier recommended to me.

Comment: @MaxM Why is it so hard just to describe what you are trying to achieve? I cannot understand why you keep your real problem secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **bad idea** and is poor practice when it comes to Maven dependencies.

First and foremost, your projects will always need to be relatively locateable to one another, which means that your build environment will have to have them together.  This translates to builds which **may not be repeatable** because there is absolutely no guarantee that the second project would not have changed between builds of the first project.

Second, the conventional way to combine multiple related projects is to have subprojects instead.  This way you can have your first project depend on your second project without any headaches.

Failing any of that, then the *best* alternative is to publish the second project to your local m2 repository or your repository store, and pulling it down in your first project.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know that is bad practice but i need that path but not for maven. I just use maven to pass it as execution parameter for another tool. Thats why i need that. Do you know how to do that without publishing it to m2 repository?

Comment: @MaxM If you need the dependencies at one place to run some tool, it would be better to use maven dependency plugin instead of trying to figure out paths. Ideal would be if you ask another question which describes the complete use case including the tool you want to send the paths to.

Comment: @JFabianMeier thank you for your suggestion but you know how can i get the relative path of dependency in pom.xml ?

Comment: @MaxM Sorry, but I am trying to help people get on the right track. I won't answer questions like the one above unless I am convinced that this is the right solution for the problem. Up to know I think you just _believe_ you need the relative paths because you are on the wrong track. See: I am just the third expert trying to convince you, but insist to get an answer to the question.